# Least squares equations and Matrix Algebra

Tags: matrix-equations, least-squares

I have a question regarding the manipulation of linear least squares equations. Suppose $x$ satisfies
$$
A x = b
$$
in a least-squares sense, where $A$ is $m \times n$ with $m > n$, $x$ is $n \times 1$ and $b$ is $m \times 1$. If I use a $QR$ factorization of $A$, I can write
\begin{align*}
A x &= b \\
QRx &= b \\
Rx &= Q^T b \\
x &= R^{-1} Q^T b
\end{align*}
and so it seems I can apply $Q^T$ and $R^{-1}$ to the rhs side of the equation without issue, since this is the well-known $QR$ least squares solution.

However, now consider the following weighted least squares problem,
$$
D A y = D b
$$
where $D$ is an $m \times m$ diagonal weighting matrix with positive values on the diagonal. In this case, it is not allowed to apply $D^{-1}$ to both sides, resulting in $Ay = b$, because we know that the solution $x$ satisfying $A x = b$ will be different from the solution $y$ satisfying the weighted system $D A y = D b$.

Can anyone explain why I can apply $Q^T$ and $R^{-1}$ to the equation in the former case, but I cannot apply $D^{-1}$ to the equation in the latter case?

Comment: How do you know that $R$ is invertible?

Comment: Lets assume $A$ is full rank and non-singular, so that $R^{-1}$ exists

Comment: The way you’ve described this, the original equation has an exact solution, so least-squares doesn’t enter into it. You need to look at the solutions of $A^TAx=A^Tb$ for that.

Answer (score 1):

Some observations here, or comments.

While it is true that if you use the $QR$ decomp and you have

$$Ax=b \\ QRx =b \\ Rx = Q^{T}b \\ x = R^{-1}Q^{T}b $$

how it actually works is through back substitution. So it never actually forms the inverse. $x$ is found in the following way. The matrix $R$ is upper triangular. So the solutions to the vector are computed recursively.

$$ x_{n} = \frac{b_{n}}{r_{nn}} \\ x_{i} = \frac{b_{i}}{r_{ii}} - \sum_{k=i+1}^{n} x_{k} \frac{r_{ik}}{r_{ii}}$$

In regards to the other part, the $QR$ decomp is a direct method. The weighting method [iterative you have.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9b92/18e7233f4d0b491e1582c893c9a099470a73.pdf)

It would depend on which one is greater.

$ m > n$

$$ x = \bigg[A^{T}D^{T}DA \bigg]^{-1}A^{T}D^{T}Db $$
$ m < n $
$$ x = \bigg[D^{T}D\bigg]^{-1}A^{T}\bigg[A (D^{T}D)^{-1}A^{T} \bigg]^{-1}b $$